# stub instance with namespaced object using Mocha Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocking, mocha.js

I am using Mocha library with test unit. https://github.com/freerange/mocha

Here is my controller action

```
def update_purchase_state
  current_state = @purchase.aasm_state
  @purchase.update_attribute :aasm_state, params[:purchase_state]
  flash[:notice] = "successfully update the purchase state from '#{current_state}' to '#{params[:purchase_state]}'"
  redirect_to home_admin_purchase_editor_path(purchase_id: @purchase)
end
```

Here is my controller test

```
should "update the purchase's state" do
  PurchaseEditor::Purchase.any_instance.expects(:aasm_state).returns("paid")
  PurchaseEditor::Purchase.any_instance.expects(:update_attribute)
  post :update_purchase_state, purchase_id: "1", purchase_state: "refunded"
  assert_response 200
  assert_match /successfully update the purchase state/, flash[:notice]
end
```

The error I am getting is undef method aasm_state for nil class.
I am confused bc I thought I was mocking it out with .any_instance.  I have also tried .stubs as well with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.any_instance` will work for instances of `Purchase`, but `@purchase` is not an instance of `Purchase`. It is `nil` in this case. You need to address where you assign `@purchase` in your controller or you need to artificially assign it yourself from the spec.

Comment: I see, so I need to return an object that responds to .aasm_state.  Thanks for ur help.